# How to display products with limits and offset

Tags: magento2, curl

I have displaying products using following url

host/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=20

Now displaying 20 products in page. i want 20 in first page, 20 to 40 products in second page, 40 to 60 products vice versa. How can i get this?

Answer (score 0):

Use currentPage param like this

```
/rest/default/V1/products/?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20&searchCriteria[currentPage]=2
```

for seconde page

```
/rest/default/V1/products/?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20&searchCriteria[currentPage]=3
```